# Mysql similar text search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like below-

```
------------
keyword_text
------------
Lego kit for kids
Lego kit only for kids
Lego kit kids

+more different text entry
```

As you can see, the **keyword_text** in above example are all similar. I want to find all those match for any of the above keywords. For example if I search for ***Lego kit only for kids*** , it will return me all of those 3 keyword_text.

```
Input:
Lego kit only for kids

Output:
Lego kit for kids
Lego kit only for kids
Lego kit kids

OR 

mysql resource to use with mysql_fetch_assoc
```

The table has approximately 1M entry and **full text index** is added to **keyword_text**. Is there any mysql query to do that or any similar way to do it quickly using PHP?

Thanks for help

Comment: you could use LIKE in your mysql query to get what you need

Comment: If you have a fulltext index, why not use fulltext search? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to look at the Levenshtein Distance between the search term and the keyword list.  There are quiet a few examples of how to implement this in MySQL, eg. [HERE](https://web.archive.org/web/20150521071538/http://www.jisaacks.com/find-similar-products-in-mysql-using-levenshtein-distance)

Because you have such a large catalogue, you will need to look at implementing a filter first (perhaps based on a 'LIKE' lookup) so that you are not measuring the distance for all 1M rows.

If you rank results by distance then you should be able to sort results by relevancy to the search.

Comment: Dead link as of 07/03/2015